# Code is not executing due to syntax error in line 18

Tags: python

My code is showing a syntax error in line 18 of the code. I am not being able to find out what the problem is. Can you guys please kindly help me out?

The problem is as follows:

3.2 Write a menu-driven program that allows the user to make transactions to a bank account. The
options of the menu are:

- Option 1: Make a Deposit
- Option 2: Make a Withdrawal
- Option 3: Obtain a Balance
- Option 4: Quit

a) First the program asks the user for his/her name.
b) The user can make many interactions as they wish until they decide to quit by pressing Q or
q from the keyboard. (Hint: while loop)
c) Assume that the account initially has a balance of £1000.
d) If the user tries to withdraw an amount more than the total balance, the program should print ‘It is
not possible to withdraw beyond the account balance
e) Ask the user to make a selection from the menu options.
f) Make sure the user enters a proper menu number.
g) If option one is selected, allow the addition of funds to the balance.
h) If option two is selected, subtract the amount from the balance.
i) If option three is selected, display the total balance of the checking account.

The code is as follows:

```
print("*******WELCOME TO OUR BANK*******")

user_name = input("Please enter your name: ")

balance = 1000

while True:
    print("Choose 1 for deposit.")
    print("Choose 2 for withdraw.")
    print("Choose 3 for balance.")
    print("Choose Q or q to exit.")
    choice = input("Please enter your option: ")
    if choice == "Q" or "q" or "1" or "2" or "3":
        break
    
if choice == "1":
    deposit = int(input("Enter an amount to deposit: GBP")
    balance = balance + deposit
    print("Entered amount has been deposited and account has been updated accordingly.")
    print("Current account balance for ", user_name,"is: GBP", balance)
    print("Thank you for banking with us.")
    
elif choice == "2":
    withdraw = int(input("Enter an amount to withdraw: GBP")
    if withdraw > balance:
        print("It is not possible to withdraw beyond the account balance.")
        print("Please try again!")
    else:
        balance = balance - withdraw
        print("Entered amount has been withdrawn and account has been updated accordingly.")
        print("Current account balance for ", user_name,"is: GBP", balance)
        print("Thank you for banking with us.")

elif choice == "3":
    print("Your current account balance for ", user_name,"is: GBP", balance)
        
elif choice == "Q" or "q":
    print("Thanks for choosing us as your bank")
    print("Visit us again!")
else:
    print("Wrong transaction! Try again.")
```

Comment: You seem to be missing closing parenthesis `)` on some lines, eg: `deposit = int(input("Enter an amount to deposit: GBP")`

Comment: Apart from the missing parenthesis, you have another issue: `if choice == "Q" or "q" or "1" or "2" or "3":` will always be true, so you will accept _any_ user input. You probably wanted to do something like `if choice in 'Qq123':`

Answer (score 0):

U must close the parentheses when calling functions

u forgot to do so in 2 occasions

On line 17 and 24
just change it from `deposit = int(input("Enter an amount to deposit: GBP")` to `deposit = int(input("Enter an amount to deposit: GBP"))`

and from `withdraw = int(input("Enter an amount to withdraw: GBP")` to `withdraw = int(input("Enter an amount to withdraw: GBP"))`